# Django rest framework not indexing a custom CBV in Api Root

Tags: django-rest-framework

In Django-rest-framework I have a simple CBV

```
class LocationList(APIView):
    """
    List all locations (id and name)
    """
    def get(self, request, format=None):
        # Make connection to SQL server db
        dbargs = dict(
            DRIVER='{FreeTDS}',
            SERVER=django_settings.DB_HOST,
            PORT=django_settings.DB_PORT,
            DATABASE=django_settings.DB_NAME,
            UID=django_settings.DB_USER,
            PWD=django_settings.DB_PWD,
        )

        cnxn = pyodbc.connect(**dbargs)    
        # Query db
        curs = cnxn.cursor()
        select_locations_cmd = 'SELECT list_id, cast(list_name as text) FROM location_lists;'
        curs = curs.execute(select_locations_cmd)

        # Serialize
        sdata = [dict(list_id=lid, list_name=lname) for lid, lname in curs.fetchall()]

        # Close cnxn
        cnxn.close()

        return Response(sdata)
```

As you can see all it does is queries an external database, manually serializes the result and returns it in a django-rest-framework `Response` object.

In my `urls.py` I have

```
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'someothermodel', SomeOtherModelViewSet)


urlpatterns = [url(r'^', include(router.urls)),
               url(r'^locationlists/$', LocationList.as_view(), name="weather-location-lists"),

               ]
```

This works OK, but what I'm concerned about is that when I visit the root API url, it only shows the endpoint for `someothermodel`, which was registered via the router and used a standard ViewSet. It doesn't list the `locationlists` endpoint at all. *I can visit the `/locationlists` endpoint in the browser (or make a GET request otherwise to it without issue), **but it's not indexed**.*

How can I index it at the root? So it appears alongside

```
Api Root
HTTP 200 OK
Allow: GET, HEAD, OPTIONS
Content-Type: application/json
Vary: Accept

{
    "someothertask": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/someothertask/",
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The page you are referring to is powered by the router and in your case `LocationList` isn't registered via the router. As such it doesn't appear in the endpoint list.

As @Linovia points out, routers only deal with viewsets. With a few changes however this is simple to achieve:

```
# views.py
from rest_framework.viewsets import ViewSet

class LocationList(ViewSet):

    def list(self, request, format=None):  # get -> list
        ...

# urls.py
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'someothermodel', SomeOtherModelViewSet)
router.register(r'locationlists', LocationList, base_name='weather-location')

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^', include(router.urls)),
]
```

You should now see:

```
{
    "someothertask": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/someothertask/",
    "locationlists": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/locationlists/",
}
```

It is worth noting that the reverse name for your view has now changed from `weather-location-lists` to `weather-location-list`, but hopefully this is minor change to the places this may have been used.

Answer (score 0):

Routers only work with `ViewSet`